# Error in code wont allow me to progress

Tags: python, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I get an error when i run this code

```
cost = float(prices[strs[0]][0])
```

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

i dont know how to fix the error

```
prices = {}
groceries = []

file = open("grocery_store_price_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file:
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    prices[strs[0]] = [strs[1]], [strs[2]]
file.close()

file = open("my_personal_gro_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file :
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    groceries.append([strs[1], strs[0]])

headings = "{:15s} {:3s} {:10s} {:5s} {:6s}".format("item", "qty", "unit", 
"cost", "total")

print(headings)
finalCost = 0

for strs in groceries
    item = strs[0]
    qty = int(strs[1])
    unit = prices[strs[0]][1]
    cost = float(prices[strs[0]][0])
```

Comment: just before the last line, add `print(prices[strs[0]][0])` & see what is the type you are passing to float. Error indicates it is list. So, your indexing logic might be incorrect.

Comment: Use `cost = float(prices[strs[0]][0][0])`. Or you might want to `prices[strs[0]] = [strs[1], strs[2]]`, which I think you wanted in the first place.

Comment: My solution converts both prices to floats, not just the first.

Comment: cost = [float(v) for v in prices[strs[0]][0]]

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you as correct. Welcome to Stack overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prices[strs[0]][0]` is a `list` that contains two prices. So you'll want to cast both values separately or using `cost = [float(v) for v in prices[strs[0]][0]]`.

```
prices = {}
groceries = []

file = open("grocery_store_price_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file:
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    prices[strs[0]] = [strs[1]], [strs[2]]  # List of two prices, why you get the error.
file.close()

file = open("my_personal_gro_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file :
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    groceries.append([strs[1], strs[0]])

headings = "{:15s} {:3s} {:10s} {:5s} {:6s}".format("item", "qty", "unit", 
"cost", "total")

print(headings)
finalCost = 0

for strs in groceries
    item = strs[0]
    qty = int(strs[1])
    unit = prices[strs[0]][1]
    cost = [float(v) for v in prices[strs[0]][0]]
    # OR  cost = [float(prices[strs[0]][0][0]), float(prices[strs[0]][0][1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> prices = {}
>>> prices['a'] = [1], [2]
>>> prices
{'a': ([1], [2])}
```

Taking above as an example, your prices contains a tuple and each is a list that contains 1 element

```
  prices[strs[0]] = [strs[1]], [strs[2]]
```

You either apply float() on one of the values or modify your `prices` let each key has one value

Comment: Believe its a ``list``

Comment: prices[strs[0]] = ``[``strs[1]], [strs[2]``]``

Comment: @alexisdevarennes thanks, it is a tuple that contains 2 single-item lists. [2] itself is a list and that should be why Op get the error